# Mui datatables pagination alignment is broken

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am using mui-datatables v ^4.2.2" with react and react-dom 17.0.2 and @mui/material v5.10.15.

When I display the datatable, my pagination alignment is broken:

[image]

It is applying some margin-bottom:
[image]

And finally these are the options for my mui datatable

> ```
> export const options = {
>   tableBodyHeight: `${window.innerHeight - 48 - 64}px`,
>   customSearchRender: () => <></>,
>   search: false,
>   selectableRows: 'none' as const,
>   setRowProps: () => {
>     return {
>       style: { cursor: 'pointer' },
>     };
>   },
> };
> ```

I didn't apply any styles, neither in theme provider, nor in sx props.
I faced this issue for the first time, and can't understand why it is happening.

If anybody has faced this issue and knows a solution, will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've used your `options: {...}` on the table but have not found any issues. Please have a look at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-wave-toqqy4?file=/src/App.js:487-613) example using the same dependencies as **mui-datatables** `^4.2.2` with **react and react-dom** `17.0.2` and **@mui/material** `5.10.15` there you can see fine as expected. Please take a look at the example. It'd be good if you provided the snippets that would help to debug in depth.

Besides, you can also have a look at the link below to see the issue and solution visually: [TestWise Replay | Stack Overflow QA - MUI data-table pagination alignment](https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/XUjIhEVweyB)

Comment: Thank you, will try it today and see if it works